# Subquery in Tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I meet a simple but hard question. I tried to perform the region distribution on the top 5 risk crossings.

The SQL is like

```
select region, count(ID) from
(select top 5 ID, region, risk from test order by risk)
group by region order by region
```

How to perform that in `Tableau`?, hope to get the idea and steps best.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
Select Analysis > Create Calculated Field.

**Step 2**
In the Create Calculated Field dialog box, do the following:

1. In the Name text box, type a name for the calculation (e.g *Ranking*)
2. In the Formula text box, type the following: INDEX() When finished,
3. Click OK.

**Step 3**
In the Measures pane, right-click the *Ranking* field, and select Convert to Discrete.

**Step 4**
Place the *Ranking* field onto the Rows shelf, before the Region field.

**Step 5**
On the Rows shelf, right-click the *Ranking* field, and select Compute Using > Pane (Down).

**Step 6**
Press the CTRL key, click the *Ranking* field, and place it on Detail.

**Step 7**
Right-click the *Ranking* field and select Continuous, and move the field to the Filter shelf.

**Step 8**
In the Filter dialog box, type 1 in the first text box and 5 in the second text box, and then click OK.

Now you can see the top 5 regions.

This solution is inspired by the KB article:  http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/finding-top-n-within-category